# Admin and user differentiate in realtime firebase auth react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am Developing an react native app for parent and tutor in which  that I am using email and password for signing in and signup used, so I want to differentiate the user and parent.

It is done with realtime firebase.

How it possible in Firebase? Please suggest me to resolve my issues.

Comment: This documentation on Custom Claims may be of use to you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: This has been covered quite a few times already, so I recommend checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+types+of+user